# How to update Web api OData Entity with a navigation property?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Entity1 has a collection of Entity2 as a navigation property. I can successfully get Entity1 from ODataController with expanded collection of Entity2. But when I try to update Entity1 using ODataController PUT or PATCH methods, I can do it only when a collection of Entity2 is null. Otherwise Delta is null.

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<ClienteleExportTemplate> delta)
```

What is interesting: when I use POST method of the same ODataController nested collection of Entity2 is filled with values and I can successfully save Entity1.
So the problem is only in PUT and PATCH methods.

This is my modelBuilder config for this entities:

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Entity1>("Entity1OData");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Entity2>("Entity2OData");
```

I send values to POST and PUT methods as an JSON array using $odataresourse module for angularJs.

How to configure Web api 2 ODatav4 to support navigation properties update?

Answer (score 1):

Currently not support update entity relationship, As workaround, you can use the $ref to update the entity relationship. Please refer here for example:

https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/eb795e26547555666410a79b88e3930d22479798/WebApiODataSample